# OpenVPN route troubles

Tags: openvpn

i've setup openvpn on my raspbarry pi. This scheme below is my current network:
[image]

With the OpenVPN client i can ping the raspbarry (on the 10.8.0.1 interface) but im not able to ping my PC desktop (192.168.1.3).I tried to add this line into the server.conf:

> push "route 192.168.1.0 255.255.255.0"

Server.conf:

```
dev tun
proto udp
port 1194
ca /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/pki/ca.crt
cert /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/pki/issued/raspberrypi_73c07827-d429-4cf4-8a0a-408772ae977f.crt
key /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/pki/private/raspberrypi_73c07827-d429-4cf4-8a0a-408772ae977f.key
dh none
ecdh-curve prime256v1
topology subnet
server 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0
# Set your primary domain name server address for clients
push "dhcp-option DNS 9.9.9.9"
push "dhcp-option DNS 149.112.112.112"
# Prevent DNS leaks on Windows
push "block-outside-dns"
# Override the Client default gateway by using 0.0.0.0/1 and
# 128.0.0.0/1 rather than 0.0.0.0/0. This has the benefit of
# overriding but not wiping out the original default gateway.
push "redirect-gateway def1"
client-to-client
client-config-dir /etc/openvpn/ccd
keepalive 15 120
remote-cert-tls client
tls-version-min 1.2
tls-crypt /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/pki/ta.key
cipher AES-256-CBC
auth SHA256
user openvpn
group openvpn
persist-key
persist-tun
crl-verify /etc/openvpn/crl.pem
status /var/log/openvpn-status.log 20
status-version 3
syslog
verb 3

#Added
push "route 192.168.1.0 255.255.255.0"


#DuplicateCNs allow access control on a less-granular, per user basis.
#Remove # if you will manage access by user instead of device. 
#duplicate-cn
# Generated for use by PiVPN.io
```

Client:

```
client
dev tun
proto udp
remote 188.153.71.125 1194
resolv-retry infinite
nobind
remote-cert-tls server
tls-version-min 1.2
verify-x509-name raspberrypi_73c07827-d429-4cf4-8a0a-408772ae977f name
cipher AES-256-CBC
auth SHA256
auth-nocache
verb 3
```

but it didnt work...
Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you please post your server and client configs?

Comment: @2ps i've updated the post, thanks for your reply

Comment: ~Apologies for the late response -- to confirm, from the raspberry pi, you can't ping 10.8.0.2~  I misread -- sorry.

Answer (score 1):

The problem that you are having is likely because you don't have masquerade setup on the raspberry pi.  [Add an up script that will add an iptables postrouting masquerade](https://community.openvpn.net/openvpn/wiki/BridgingAndRouting?__cf_chl_jschl_tk__=l8VARdDW63oAUgvuBF9Ggp9c8c5AbAOCFFtz_naWObI-1639868146-0-gaNycGzNCpE), and that should allow the 10.8.0.2 pc to ping 192.168.1.3.

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.8.0.0/24 -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
```

You may have to change `eth0` based on the configuration of your interfaces on the raspberry pi.

n.b., you will also have to make sure `net.ipv4.ip_forward` is set to `1` in `sysctl`